# Homomorphism image of maximal torus

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, compactness, connectedness, group-homomorphism

I’m asked to show given a surjective homomorphism between compact connected Lie groups: $G$ and $H$, then maximal torus in $G$ are mapped to maximal torus in $H$. Well, I’m not sure how can I  use the subjectivity to show that the torus we get by homomorphism is actually maximal. I doubt the maximal torus theorem comes into play, but I don’t see how, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Let $S$ be a compact connected Lie group, $K$ being a normal closed subgroup of $S$. If the factor group $S/K$ is an Abelian group, then there exists a connected closed Abelian subgroup $R$ of $S$ such that $S=KR$ and $|R\cap K|<\infty$.
2. Let $G$ and $H$ be compact connected groups Lie,
   $T$ being a maximal torus of $G$,
   $f:G\rightarrow H$ being a surjective homomorphism.
   Since $f(T)$ is a connected Abelian subgroups of $H$,
   there exists a maximal torus $T'$ of $H$ such that $f(T)<T'$.
   Let $S=f^{-1}(T')$ and $K=Ker(f)$. Then $S/K\cong T'$ is an Abelian group.

Comment: Why this help? I don’t see I have an abelian group that can be dealt with...

Comment: Why might it help?
Completed my answer, since there is no way to work with formulas in the comments.

Comment: Well, I see your argument, but why Ker$(f)$ is contained in $T$ and $f^{-1}(T')$?

Comment: By definition, $S=f^{-1}(T')=\{x\in G\mid f(x)\in T'\}$ and $f(T)<T'$. It follows that $K=Ker(f)<S$ and $T<S$. I did not claim that $K<T$.

Comment: We can also continue our reasoning like this.We have that $KT$ is normal in $S$ and $T$ is a maximal torus of $S<G$. Since any $x\in S$ is contained in a conjugate of $T$, it follows that $KT=S$.

Comment: Then I doubt I misunderstood your point... Would you like to elaborate on which point you imply the maximality of $T$?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand your last question.
T is the maximal torus in G, hence in S<G.
Is that what you mean?